# PayPay UK Business account any way to not have to create account on checkout

Tags: paypal

I've a UK standard PayPal business account setup on my website.

PayPal's own site says

`Accept **card payments** and PayPal Give buyers the ease and security of paying you directly from their PayPal account.  on your website`

Can I turn off the requirement for paypal account creation when  customers check out with paypal express standard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you aren't using PayPal Express Checkout, this is ONLY for PayPal account holders and that you have set up Paypal Standard for starters.

Next, log into Paypal,

Click profile > Click my selling tools > Website Payment Preferences > and the section "PayPal Account Optional" is turned ON

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I cannot find any info on the PayPal site but I did find it in my stores setup.